# What is a rolling shutter? When do I have to be aware of it?

Tags: camera-basics, rolling-shutter, shutter

In answer to [another question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4115/problem-with-fluorescent-lighting-and-shutter-speed/4141#4141), Adam Davis writes:

> Your camera complicates this by using
>   a rolling shutter above a given speed
>   (usually around 1/200. This means that
>   only a portion of the image sensor is
>   exposed to the scene at any given
>   time, so if the light changes during
>   the exposure, the color change will
>   only affect a portion of the image
>   sensor.

Rolling shutters often are also mentioned in the [context of DSLR videography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9223/why-do-dslrs-in-movie-mode-have-a-rolling-shutter-instead-of-a-global-shutter).  However, I am yet to see a discussion of what a rolling shutter is, how it works and when it is important.

What is a rolling shutter?

What are the implications of using one for my photos?

Comment: What Adam is talking about is not actually a rolling shutter, it's just a focal plane shutter.  It also does nothing special above 1/200.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**What Adam is referring to**

What Adam is talking about is not actually a rolling shutter, it's just a focal plane shutter. It also does nothing special above 1/200, except that the effect of the shutter curtain has some interesting properties which can become more pronounced at higher speed.

The [diagrams on the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal-plane_shutter) (reproduced below) illustrate it best.  Essentially the shutter consists of two curtains which move from top to bottom (or in some film cameras, left to right) in quick succession.  The gap between them is what exposes the image.

[image: Focal plane shutter, low speed]

*Focal-plane shutter, low speed.  Black square is the sensor, red and green squares are the first and second curtains*.

[image: Focal plane shutter, high speed]

*Focal-plane shutter, high speed.  Black square is the sensor, red and green squares are the first and second curtains*.

If the shutter speed is fast enough, the second one will start closing before the first one has fully finished opening, so the entire frame won't all be exposed at once.  Therefore, you get a situation where anything that happens really fast, like the flash of a camera or the oscillation of a fluorescent light, may cause light not to cover the entire frame but instead create bands or gradients from top to bottom where the light is different.

The diagrams show the shutters moving horizontally as they did in most 35mm mechanical film cameras, whereas modern cameras with electronically controlled shutters (film or digital) almost universally have vertical shutters. It's the same effect but in a ninety degree different direction.

**What a rolling shutter effect is**

The *rolling shutter effect* as it applies to digital video is quite a different and quite unrelated effect to the one described above.  Actually, a rolling shutter effect does not actually involve a physical shutter, but it's called that as a convention because it is analogous to the way a film cinema camera has a shutter that moves across the frame.  In digital video, the rolling shutter effect is the result of the way a CMOS sensor is read.

CMOS sensors exhibit a rolling shutter effect when they are in live view or video mode, in which they are being read for every video frame. Instead of capturing the entire frame at once, information is read from each row of the frame one after the other, top to bottom. The whole process takes up to 1/30 of a second on most cameras. This creates a jelly-like wobbling effect in recorded video when the camera is handheld or moves a lot.

In a given sensor, this rolling shutter happens equally regardless of the shutter speed, though with slower shutter speeds it may be less noticeable in subject movement because of the extra motion blur.  The effect is not usually noticeable when the camera is fixed on a tripod or panned steadily, but is more obvious when the camera is hand-held or during fast camera movements.

CMOS sensors capable of higher frame rates than 30 frames per second (and not just through repeating frames) will exhibit less rolling shutter effect because their sensors will have been designed to be read faster.

CCD does not suffer from the rolling shutter effect.

Comment: +1 Great explanation, thank you.  I've inserted the referenced images from wikipedia, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Yep that's good, thanks.  In case people are wondering, the diagrams show the shutters moving horizontally whereas modern cameras seem to have vertical shutters.  Same effect though.

Comment: I made a similar question and was down-voted, because this explanation does not show up in the search. Thanks for the explanation on matrices.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if a video that is shot with a rolling-shutter camera is shown on a CRT whose scan pattern matches that of the camera, the artifacts created by the rolling shutter will be reversed by the scanning action of the CRT.  For example, a video of near-vertical lines moving from right to left would skew them so the bottom was shifted to the left, but a CRT showing a video of near-vertical lines would skew them so the bottom appeared shifted to the right.  I don't know of any modern displays that try to accurately emulate such behavior, however.

Comment: @supercat I wonder if anyone has tried to write a video player/codec/format that would artificially reverse the line rolling shutter effect digitially

Comment: The [*Rolling shutter* Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter) disagrees with the opening sentences of the "**What a rolling shutter effect is**" section above. From WP: "Rolling shutter ... is captured not by taking a snapshot of the entire scene at a single instant in time but rather by scanning across the scene rapidly"; and, "the 'rolling shutter' can be either mechanical or electronic."

Comment: Indeed, the classic ["leaning" 1920's race car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter) image is exactly a *rolling shutter* effect caused by a wiping shutter progressively exposing the scene from bottom to top.

Comment: Did you read the part of my answer that says "it is analogous to the way a film cinema camera has a shutter that moves across the frame".  I specifically pointed out this is equivalent to an effect on film cinema cameras *and* that that's where it got the name rolling shutter.  So thanks for your "correction" I guess.  The question was specifically in regards to DSLR cameras, which is why I primarily addressed rolling shutter effect in that type of camera.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that there is some contradiction or confusion with what's stated In a common (albeit by no means *canonical*) reference source people might refer to.

Comment: My answer is consistent with what you pointed out on Wikipedia.  Where do you think the contradiction is?

Comment: I've already pointed out where I think the contradiction is. However, I'm more than happy to defer to your answer as it stands, which has certainly earned its place by standing as it has for the last 3 years AND is the accepted answer. =)

Comment: The term *rolling shutter* was in use for at least half a century before the existence of electronic imaging with the invention of television cameras. It was most often used in the context of movie cameras, but was around before their invention as well.

Comment: Do I need to make that information more prominent in my answer?  A couple of comments now have "corrected" me on this even though I thought I did address it in the answer.

Comment: @thomasrutter Well, when you say things such as, "Actually, a rolling shutter effect does not actually involve a physical shutter, but it's called that as a convention because it is analogous to the way a film cinema camera has a shutter that moves across the frame." it seems to indicate that you are rejecting the fact that the term was used LONG before digital video was invented!

Comment: That quote appears in a paragraph specifically talking about how it applies to digital video. In the preceding sentence I wrote "as it applies to digital video". The point is that with digital video there is not a physical shutter, but you can still get the rolling shutter effect. This is a fairly important thing to understand if you come in thinking that it is somehow caused by a physical shutter. Within the same quoted section I then go on to explain the origin of the term in film. You'd have to skip over the start and end of that paragraph to miss that context.

Comment: The second part is not really correct. It *is* related to the shutter, only most electronic shutters also read out the sensor line by line, so they can *also* suffer from the rolling shutter effect. https://www.slrlounge.com/electronic-shutter-vs-mechanical-shutter-pros-cons/ . With a mechanical shutter, the effect is caused by the two shutter blades being too slow to open completely. So only a line of the sensor is lit at one time, this line moves over the sensor. If something is very fast, it will be in a different place when the top is lit, compared to the bottom.

Comment: @rickboender I have to say I really don't see where you're coming from or if you've commented in the right place.  You say: "most electronic shutters also read out the sensor line by line, so they can also suffer from the rolling shutter effect" - yes, this is the *entire* point I was making in my answer. I've even used similar words to you - "instead of capturing the entire frame at once, information is read from each row of the frame one after the other, top to bottom" - this is right in the answer you commented on.

Comment: @thomasrutter : You start with the heading 'What a rolling shutter effect is', but then you subtlely talk only talk about digital video, and say that the effect has nothing to do with physical shutters, it may be correct for video, but i find it very confusing. You also say that the effect is completely different and unrelated to the effect with a physical shutter, but I think it is exactly the same, the only difference is that with a physical shutter, the sensor is *lit* row by row, and in digital it is *read* row by row, the physical principle is the same. Maybe change the heading a bit?

Comment: When I say the rolling shutter effect in digital video is "unrelated to the effect above", I mean it is unrelated to the effect of a focal plane shutter on still cameras. But, it is a very similar effect to the one you get with rolling shutters on film cine cameras. I even say it is "analogous to" that effect - it's not exactly the same, since in the latter, technically the film isn't lit row by row, but by a [rotating shutter](https://i.imgur.com/qpkux5R.jpg).

Answer (score 15):

The rolling shutter is a method of image capture which is not by taking a snapshot of the entire scene at single instant in time, but rather by scanning across the scene rapidly (vertically or horizontally).

The implications of using a rolling shutter can produce predictable distortions of fast-moving objects or rapid flashes of light such as wobble (jello effects), skew, smear and partial exposure.

Few examples:

[image: A photo of a Eurocopter EC-120]

> The rotor blades seem to be swept back more than usual due to the rolling shutter effect.

[image: lighting]

> A photo exhibiting partial exposure. Lighting conditions changed between the exposure of the top and bottom parts of the photo.

[image: picture by The Slow Mo Guys]

> Shadow of champagne cork shows that it already hit the face, however cork is still suspended in the air.

This back-in-time phenomenon can be explained by the following animation (where changing colour indicates a shutter rolling vertically from the top to the bottom):

[image: champagne cork blasting into the face by The Slow Mo Guys]

Here is demonstration by [The Slow Mo Guys](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmjeCchGRQo) how a rolling shutter works based on Canon EOS 7D:

[image: a rolling shutter in slow motion]

Related:

- [What happened to the blades in this picture?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21446/2673)
- [What is referred to as CMOS sensor rolling shutter width?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/97891/11197)
- [Is this picture of a bent propeller genuine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/32633/8014)

See more:

- (video) [Inside a Camera at 10,000fps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmjeCchGRQo) by The Slow Mo Guys at YouTube
- [The Math Behind the Rolling Shutter Phenomenon](http://petapixel.com/2014/10/13/math-behind-rolling-shutter-phenomenon/)
- [Full analysis of rolling shutter](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yc9znckbcg) (simulation of propeller)
- [Rolling shutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter) at Wikipedia
- [Airplane Prop + CMOS Rolling Shutter = WTF](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sorenragsdale/3192314056/) ([article 1](http://petapixel.com/2014/10/13/math-behind-rolling-shutter-phenomenon/), [article 2](http://danielwalsh.tumblr.com/post/54400376441/playing-detective-with-rolling-shutter-photos))

  [image: An iPhone's CMOS camera has no shutter, and reads the pixel values off in rows rather than all at once. In this photo the propeller spins about 5 times while the photo is taken, producing a strange effect]

Comment: Except that champagne cork sequence was shot using video with the mechanical shutter open the entire time - and since the image is inverted on the sensor, the sensor scans from the bottom to top of the sensor (top to bottom of the inverted image). If it was taken using the mechanical shutter in "stills" mode, the cork would be way ahead of the shadow because the bottom of the frame (top of the sensor) would have been exposed first. Please see [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80063/15871) for more detail about this specific test.

Answer (score 8):

Adam's terminology is slightly out - you don't get a rolling shutter above 1/200s or so, but one whose where the bottom edge starts to close before the top edge has fully opened, but the effect is the same (a rolling shutter implies the scene is constantly read out from top to bottom).

Effectively what you get at high speeds is a slit that moves up the sensor exposing one part at a time. This has implications for large changes in lighting during the exposure, such as flash, or in the original context florescent lights which vary during the AC cycle.

Lots of related questions for further reading:

- [Why do DSLRs in movie mode have a rolling shutter instead of a global shutter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9223/why-do-dslrs-in-movie-mode-have-a-rolling-shutter-instead-of-a-global-shutter)
- [What is sync speed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/what-is-sync-speed)
- [What exactly is flash sync speed, and should it be a factor in a buying decision?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/836/flash-sync-speed-buying-decision-factor)
- [Which cameras can sync at faster than 1/250?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8483/which-cameras-can-sync-at-faster-than-1-250)

Comment: No, a rolling shutter doesn't imply that the image is read repeatedly.

Comment: Doesn't it? see my comment on your answer!

Comment: The name of Ottomar Anschutz' internal focal plane shutter invented in 1883 was the "internal roller blind shutter". This was for still cameras, not movie cameras. Prior to that rolling shutters were placed in front of the lens. The term has been around a long time.

Answer (score 0):

This [movie on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvZ6VujbhjM&feature=player_embedded) is the best explanation of this I've seen.

I discovered it on [this page on DYI photography site](http://www.diyphotography.net/understanding-flash-sync-shutter-curtains-and-high-speed-sync)

Comment: You might also want to watch this [explanation on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP1elMR5qjc)

Answer (score 0):

The shutter is actually two shutters, one that slides up and one that slides down. One is used to start the exposure and the other one is used to end the exposure.

It takes a little bit of time to open a shutter, so if there was only one shutter there would be a difference in exposure time between the top and the bottom of the image. If for example the shutter needs 1/1000 s. to open, that would mean a 20% difference in exposure time between the top and the bottom when exposed at 1/100 s.

The term *rolling shutter* is used when the second shutter starts to close before the first shutter has finished opening. In the extreme case this means that there is just a thin opening that rolls across the film/sensor. You could get the same function from a single shutter in the form of a curtain with an opening that rolls across the media, but that construction would give you less flexibility when it comes to exposure times.

Comment: I would disagree on the terminology, rolling implies something is constantly happening in a cycle, such as a rolling roster or rolling substitutes in sport, and as such only applies to repeatedly reading the image line by line electronically as in live view, not to the operation of a mechanical shutter.

Comment: @Matt Grum: This, for example, disagrees with you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter

Comment: That's Wikipedia for you, the article seems to contradict itself on the subject: *"This method is implemented by rolling (moving) the shutter across the exposable image area instead of exposing the image area all at the same time (the shutter could be either mechanical or electronic). The advantage of this method is that the image sensor can continue to gather photons during the acquisition process, thus increasing sensitivity."* How can the image sensor continue to gather photons using a mechanical rolling shutter?

Comment: n.b. I didn't downvote you, the rest of your answer contains useful info, despite a difference of opinion of the definition of rolling...

Comment: Wikipedia likes to contradict itself sometimes.  See also the article on the focal plane shutter which at no point refers to it as a "rolling shutter" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal-plane_shutter - amusingly they even include the same helicopter image as an example of a focal plane shutter effect.  I think, and this is what I personally feel, that it's a common misconception that that is what a "rolling shutter" is.

Comment: The term *rolling shutter* was in use for at least half a century before the existence of electronic imaging with the invention of television cameras. It was most often used in the context of movie cameras, but was around before their invention as well.